# Dynamic AJAX Meteor website - how to make it crawlable?

Tags: seo, meteor, phantomjs, adsense

I have a Meteor project that has the spiderable package added to it. If I load the page normally and then do `view page source` I don't get anything in the `<body>` tag. If I enter the url and then add the ugly `?_escaped_fragment_=` at the end and look at the page source again - everything shows up as it should. I think this means that the spiderable package is working and is correctly rendering the HTML with `phantomJS`. So the question now is, how do I make the regular URL without the ugly part become crawlable ? I want to submit the site to google Adsense and the ugly url is not accepted, trying to see what google sees with the http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/spider/ tool results in an empty result. Any suggestions/helps ?

Edit 1: Adding the google crawl result from Google Webmaster

```
Date: Saturday, April 5, 2014 at 8:13:45 PM PDT
Googlebot Type: Web
Download Time (in milliseconds): 304
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 06 Apr 2014 03:13:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/7a2b57749c356bfba1728bdae88febf653d0c6ca.css?meteor_css_resource=true">


<script type='text/javascript'>__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"0.7.2","PUBLIC_SETTINGS":{"ga":{"account":"UA-********-1"}},"ROOT_URL":"http://****.***","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","autoupdateVersion":"8213872485a2cc1cff2745d78330d7c8db8d8899"};</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/caefe2b2510e562c5e310f649c4ff564ddb6b519.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
if (typeof Package === 'undefined' || 
    ! Package.webapp || 
    ! Package.webapp.WebApp || 
    ! Package.webapp.WebApp._isCssLoaded()) 
  document.location.reload(); 
</script>

<meta name="fragment" content="!">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit 2:
 For now it seems that Google indexes the site correctly, but adsense doesn't use the same policies, which is the core of this issue for me. Meteor + spiderable + phantomjs = incompatibe for AdSense = but...compatible for indexing by Google.

Comment: Does the spiderable package explicitly implement Google's AJAX crawling policy? I wouldn't count on the "fetch as google" function work for AJAX pages, but the crawl may still be successful (when submitting the original URL). Have you read https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/? All this is to say, I think it might be working just fine. Just wait for a few days, then search for your page on google, and look what google has in the cache, and whether it is indexing words in your AJAX content.

Comment: It sounds like the tool you're using doesn't use Google's [AJAX crawling specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/). Try signing up for a [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) and add your site. This will allow you to see the actual crawl result from Google's crawler.

Comment: Are you saying that google's crawler would be able to discover the ugly url, but the spider tool doesn't ? I did look through the ajax-crawling page, but it seems like all the suggestions there already work with the site. I guess, I'll try resubmitting to see if it works now.

Comment: When I use that tool to try and spider http://www.meteor.com, it says that the spider sees 1 word of text. This is clearly wrong; the Meteor homepage is indexed thoroughly in the Google search results. This suggests that that spider tool does not implement the AJAX crawling specification that Google uses to spider realtime sites.

Comment: @sbking I've added the result from google's crawl, it yields similar results. Also the spiderable package should be implementing the correct Google AJAX crawling specifications. Do you have any experience with spiderable/deploying anywhere else but the default meteor.com server ?

Comment: The `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` should be telling Google to spider the page with the `?_escaped_fragment_=` query. [See this EventedMind video on the subject](https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-the-spiderable-package). I'm not sure why your site isn't being crawled properly. I'll do some testing and see what happens.

Comment: I thought so, but it doesn't seem to be happening. I'll look at that video again, but it just might be a meteor specific thing, it's still in preview. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be simply how Google is reporting the crawling in the Webmaster Tools. After some testing with a dummy app, it appears that even though the Google Webmaster Tools reports that it fetched the empty page, the site still gets crawled, indexed, and cached properly on Google.

So for some reason, it shows the result for the pretty URL, even though the ugly URL is the actual page getting crawled, as expected. This doesn't seem like it would be a problem that is specific to Meteor, but rather with the Webmaster Tools. The `spiderable` package appears to be working as expected.

After all, http://meteor.com, http://docs.meteor.com, and http://atmosphere.meteor.com are all running Meteor and they are indexed/cached fine on Google.

One way you can verify that your site is being crawled without submitting it to be indexed is to look at the thumbnail of the site on your Webmaster Tools homepage:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

Comment: Well, the screenshot is correct...at least it was for the previous version that I had. It renders properly. It's only when I use a browser like Lynx...or use a PhantomJS script that it seems like I'm getting what the crawlers are getting - empty page. I tried submitting the page again for adsense and the crawler still wasn't able to find my content properly.

Comment: Lynx won't work unless you use the ugly URL. Rest assured that Google and other search engines that use Google's AJAX spec are crawling and indexing your pages correctly. However, a quick search shows that Adsense does not support AJAX websites. There used to be an "Adsense for AJAX" service, but Google discontinued it. It seems for now that Adsense is not the advertising service you want to use for AJAX heavy sites such as Meteor sites.

Comment: Yeah, none of the headless ones do without the ugly one. I do think google`s crwaler is seeing it properly and that's why it's a mystery why their adsense crawler would see anything else, I would think it uses whatever has been indexed before by the googlebot, but I guess not. I thought their Adsense for AJAX just merged into adsense after they made the guidelines for crawling ajax sites.

Answer (score -1):

If you're running Apache you could setup a *mod_rewrite* rewrite rule that would push every 404 error to a script.  The script would would check if the requests was pointing to special folder (like the 'content' folder below) and try to pull the content for the corresponding ugly url.

The change to the .htaccess file would look something this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /director.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The *director.php* script would work something like this:

- Check if the 404 request is targeting a specfic folder like 'content'

  - Example: http: //myplace.com/content/f-re=feedddffv
- Convert the unknown URL into an ugly URL and use CURL to get and serve the content

  - http: //myplace.com/content/f-re=feedddffv becomes http: //myplace.com/?f-re=feedddffv
- The the script uses CURL to pull the ugly url's content into a varible
- Echo the content to the viewer

You also need to create a site map for the search engine with the new pretty links.  You can done something similar in IIS with URL rewriter.  Using something like CURL can slow so try to keep your sitemap away from human eyes if possible.

Comment: Not sure what meteor is doing on the backend, but it would probably be nginx. It should be much simpler than what you've suggested. It feels like that way I would be fooling google and that might be against their user policies for ads/analytics. Thanks anyway.